# What are the argument premuations of the DrillDownMember function (SQL Server definition)?

Tags: sql-server, mdx, activepivot

The SQL Server function definition for [DrilldownMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/drilldownmember-mdx?view=sql-server-ver16) is:

```
DrillDownMember(<Set_Expression1>, <Set_Expression2> 
                [,[<Target_Hierarchy>]] [,[RECURSIVE][,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS]])
```

What is the full range of possible calls to this function?  I am not clear on the optional keyword arguments.  Since they are both in one set of brackets `[,[RECURSIVE][,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS]]`, does it mean only one of the two keyword arguments can be used?

What I would like to determine is all the permutations of this function definition.  I believe it is:

```
DrillDownMember(setExp1, setExp2)
DrillDownMember(setExp1, setExp2, targetHier)
DrillDownMember(setExp1, setExp2, targetHier, RECURSIVE)
DrillDownMember(setExp1, setExp2, targetHier, INCLUDE_CALC_MEMEBRS)
DrillDownMember(setExp1, setExp2, RECURSIVE)
DrillDownMember(setExp1, setExp2, INCLUDE_CALC_MEMEBRS)
```

Am I reading the function definition correctly?